# Kentico Xperience REST service: Request error when accessing the custom table data using Hash Authentication

Tags: kentico

I'm getting a request error message in Kentico Xperience REST service.

I followed the [documentation](https://docs.xperience.io/integrating-3rd-party-systems/xperience-rest-service/authenticating-rest-requests)

And I used Hash parameter.

This works using Hash Authentication => http://localhost:81/Admin_Site/rest

However when accessing custom tables using Hash Authentication like this one => http://localhost:81/Admin_Site/rest/customtableitem.sitenamespace.tablename

I'm getting a Request Error.

[Request error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKCLP.png)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiQEc.png)

I can only access it when entering the admin credentials.
[Window to enter Kentico global admin credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqSeV.png)

Please help

Comment: What version and hotfix are you using? What is the URL you have authenticated to be used in REST? Keep in mind that it has to be entire URL. So, the authenticated URL could look like this: http://localhost/rest/customtableitem.customtable.test?hashexpirationutc=2022-12-14T12:45:25.0000000Z&hash=dfbf977dc1e226c3bdfb90165dc5f395b38dd17004b2bfcd092463cc3988ef2b 
Or, without the URL hash - then you need to add the authentication header and use the credentials of an user account with appropriate permissions:

Comment: Kentico 13, hotfix 78. Yes, the authenticated URL looks like your example. I generated it from Generate authentication hash in REST Settings. The URL without hash would work but I had to enter the admin credentials.

Comment: why don't you add the user credentials into the REST call headers? I would try generating the hash for the entire URL one more time.

Comment: I was having these errors when adding the credentials in the headers: 

**Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"**

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at http://localhost:81/Admin_Site/rest/customtableitem.sitenamespace.tablename?format=xml from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. **


I also regenerated the hash couple of times already and I still got the error

Comment: What is your domain setup? You should be using the same domain in your REST API calls as it is set for the admin app.

Comment: It is the same domain as the admin app

Comment: Then please check this with your system admins on how the servers are configured and whether all the server features for REST are installed.

Comment: I was able to solve it. It was the security settings. Thanks.